# MySQL: select closest date before specific date

Tags: mysql, sql

How to select only closest date (select full row) before specific date for each `user_id`? (select single row for each user)

table sample:

```
id     user_id     create_date
0         1         2016-01-01
1         1         2016-01-05
2         2         2016-01-06
3         3         2016-01-06
4         2         2016-01-09
5         2         2016-01-12
6         4         2016-01-15
7         1         2016-01-21
8         2         2016-01-22
9         5         2016-01-25
```

SQL sample: (seems not working as expected)

```
select t.id,t.user_id,MAX(t.create_date)
from sample_table t
where date(t.create_date) < '2016-01-20'
group by t.user_id
limit 10
```

expected result:

```
id     user_id     create_date
1         1         2016-01-05
3         3         2016-01-06
5         2         2016-01-12
6         4         2016-01-15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sample data, the `id`s increase as the `create_date` increases.  This seems reasonable, and if true, you can use:

```
select max(t.id) as id, t.user_id, MAX(t.create_date)
from sample_table t
where date(t.create_date) < '2016-01-20'
group by t.user_id;
```

I don't think the `date()` function is needed in the `where` clause; that prevents an index from being used (if appropriate).

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
select 
    t.id, t.user_id, t.create_date
from 
    sample_table t
inner join
    (
        select 
            user_id, MAX(create_date) max_create_date
        from 
            sample_table 
        where 
            date(create_date) < '2016-01-20';
        group by 
            user_id
    ) t1
on
    t.user_id = t1.user_id and t.create_date = t1.max_create_date;
```

Comment: Is there more performance solution, rather than "join" and "nested query"?

Comment: @mwafi For **mysql**, I think **no**. For others like postgreSQL, oracle, SQL server >= 2012 you can you **analytic fucntion** like `MAX(t.create_date) over (partition by t.user_id order by t.user_id)` in your original query, use select distinct and dont need group by.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested selects:

```
select * from 
     (select * from sample_table where 
          date(create_date) < '2016-01-20' 
          order by user_date desc 
     )t 
group by user_id
```

here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ff17/1)

Comment: This will not guarantee, selected row will be the closest.

Comment: Why not?, this will return max date before the date specified for each user_id